# Netbeans - Clone specific branch of bitbucket repository

Tags: java, git, netbeans, bitbucket

I would like to clone just a specific branch of a BitBucket repository through netbeans.

Is something like this possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Git repository it is simple.

- In menu press Team > Git > Clone
- Input URL your repository:
  https://bitbucket.org/xxxxx/xxxxx.git and press Next
- Select Checkbox(es) with required branch(es)

  If the you type 'git branch -v' in project folder then you will see
  your branch name

Step 1 [image]

Step 2 [image]